# Missing quotes on JSON (from Javascript object) in JAVA

Tags: java, json, parsing, quotes

I have a Java Application, which receives a very large "Javascript Object" (like JSON format) from a server (+30k characters).

Original:

```
  String json ={  
   ok=true,
   data=   {  
      key1=1.0,
      key2=      [  
         1.5,
         1.5,
         1.5
      ],
      key3=      [  
         {  
            ts=1.526552846892E12,
            msg="random_message"
         },
         {  
            ts=1.526552846892E12,
            msg="random_message"
         }
      ]
   }
};
```

The main problem is that actually, I'm receiving something like this:

```
  String json ={  
   ok=true,
   data=   {  
      key1=1.0,
      key2=      [  
         1.5,
         1.5,
         1.5
      ],
      key3=      [  
         {  
            ts=1.526552846892E12,
            msg=random_message
         },
         {  
            ts=1.526552846892E12,
            msg=random_message
         }
      ]
   }
};
```

Note, that I "lost" the quotes on msg.

The main problem of this is that I can't parse the JSON with JSONObject for example, cause it can't read this "incorrect" format.

**Update:**

Ignoring the problem that I'm receiving a "corrupted Object", I have the problem that I can't parse this because it's a JS Object (not pure JSON).

Which is the best way to add double quotes in keys and string values?

Example of formatted JSON:

```
String json ={  
   "ok":true,
   "data":   {  
      "key1":1.0,
      "key2":      [  
         1.5,
         1.5,
         1.5
      ],
      "key3"=      [  
         {  
            "ts":1.526552846892E12,
            "msg":"random_message"
         },
         {  
            "ts":1.526552846892E12,
            "msg":"random_message"
         }
      ]
   }
};
```

Comment: How are you reading the json?

Comment: If you are receiving malformed JSON, the easiest course of action would be to have the provider correct the problem, rather than you sanitize malformed data.

Comment: The problem is that the provider gives a correct format, cause I'm taking it also with a js script and the format is correct.

Comment: How are you parsing it?

Comment: I'm taking it from a PlayFab function [link](https://api.playfab.com/documentation/client/method/ExecuteCloudScript). 
It returns to me a PlayFabResult object (it's like a string). 
As expected, it returns me the JSON broked. 
You said that it's possible to sanitize the data.. Is there an "easy" way, to fix this without getting a head-explosion?

Comment: I don't see any valid JSON syntax in either of the examples you provided.

Comment: As I tried to said in the description, it's a Javascript Object (the only difference between JSON and JS Object.. is the quotes on key.

Comment: {key1=1.0} is not valid JSON.

Comment: Yeah I'm inclined to think this is an artifact of your renderer more than anything else.

Comment: Well, my first problem was that I was receiving a "corrupted Object". But you are right. Probably, I should "add" quotes in Key and in String values, due to have a valid JSON format. 
Am I right? 
There is any way, to "automatize" this proces?

Comment: Can you show what your expected output is, after converting it into the format you want? I don't think equal signs would still be in there.

Comment: I guess what I'm confused about is: if you are able to parse it as a javascript object, why do you need to parse it as JSON?

Comment: Cause my idea is to do something like:
String myMessage= json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("key3").getJSONObject("msg").toString();
Can I do this without parse it as JSON?

Comment: Use nashhorn to parse JS object and stringify it .

Comment: @SpykeRel04D you want to access data. If you are able to read it as a JS object, you can simply access it as a JS object. When I look at the data, it does not look like a valid JS object to me, but if you are saying you can read it as a JS object then you do not need to deal with JSON at all. For example you can just say `yourObj.data.key3.msg`.

Comment: @ThatUmbrellaGuy Also it changes : to equals. But I assume isn't a problem to substitute all equals for ":". But the problem with it, is that i don't know how to indicate to Java, that it is a js object.

Comment: I guess you need to use ScriptEngine inside your Java, so you can run JavaScript interpreter. And then somehow read the data, then convert JS object to JSON string output in JavaScript, so you can read from Java.

Comment: Another alternative, write a NodeJS wrapper for the source service, that provides correct JSON output.